# If element does not exist, continue the job anyway try: except NoSuchElementException: pass

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to make a job continue if no element is found for this [site](http://centrebet.com/#Sports/59321923):
I have tried using:

```
try:
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

As well as `if then` statements.  However, the former method does not work and if then methods seem to break easily.
I have chosen this [page](http://centrebet.com/#Sports/59321923) with no text on it to see how it handles a page where elements do not exist.

```
try:
    # Team ODDS
    time.sleep(4)
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.brdSports td td tr:nth-child(1) .sport-namerow .left'))))
    langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".brdSports td td tr:nth-child(1) .sport-namerow .left")
    #tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr: eq(1) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td:eq(1) > table > tbody > tr: eq(0) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td:eq(0) > div > div
    langs_text = []

    for lang in langs:
        print(lang.text)
        langs_text.append(lang.text)

    time.sleep(0)
    time.sleep(4)
    # BACK TEAM
    #langs1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='runners']//li[2]")
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.brdSports td td tr:nth-child(1) .sport-namerow .txtBld'))))
    langs1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".brdSports td td tr:nth-child(1) .sport-namerow .txtBld")
    langs1_text = []

    for lang in langs1:
        print(lang.text)
        langs1_text.append(lang.text)

    url1 = driver.current_url

    time.sleep(0)

    with open('vtg12.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in zip(langs_text, langs1_text):
            writer.writerow(row + (url,))
            print(row + (url,))
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Full [code](https://pastebin.com/QSwRbXJM)

Comment: What exactly happens when you use the `except NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: @BenWurth For me I still got error.   I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/centa testing.py", line 1785, in <module>
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.brdSports td td tr:nth-child(1) .sport-namerow .left'))))
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: It looks like you need to make an additional `except` clause for Selenium's `TimeoutException`.

Comment: @BenWurth Can you provide an example of how to do that

Comment: @BenWurth HMMM.. except TimeoutException as ex: might have worked.. doing further testing.  Yeap pretty sure thats working now, awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the stacktrace you posted in the comments, you need to add an additional exception for Selenium's `TimeoutException`.

This should work:

```
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

Comment: This works well for a single page, however I'm trying to loop through a series of pages with: https://pastebin.com/WymkYUs4 .

Comment: Put the `try except` inside of the `for` loop so it gets checked every loop.